# Why should the Help Page provide information on the website only?

Tags: discussion, help-center, help

The [Help Center of Buddhism SE](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help) is very resourceful for including a list of resources, which in my experience the only site that make use of this section.

Some arguments:

- > Putting content about the **subject of the site** (in this case, Buddhism) pushes down the content about the **site itself** (Buddhism SE)

  → This is true, but what is the harm? If the site itself is that important, why is the homepage allowed to be edited? Is it really true that only the latter is the one most visitors are going to be looking for? I'm a simple man. I need help, I visit help center.
- > That Help Center page is not curated by the community, there is no ability for community members to edit it, and most importantly, there's no ability for anyone to vote on it

  → There can very well have a meta post to decide what to write in there, so it has been voted on already and can still be continually contributed by the community.

Comment: We can't really know. Each site is on its own, with its own set of moderators. Try asking on some sites meta or even chat, your chance you get honest answer this way is bigger.

Comment: That actually looks like a very bad idea. None of that content has anything to do with the website itself, and therefore does not belong in the Help Center. It also pushes down the actual Help Center information that most visitors are going to be looking for.

Comment: @CodyGray I think you mean the content about **the subject** pushes down the help information about the **site**. We should identify whether visitors go to that page to find what kind of information.

Comment: Yes, of course. The Help Center is designed to provide information on the website itself, not on the subject. If you're looking for information on the subject, you search the website. This is the whole point of Q&A. That Help Center page is *not* curated by the community, there is no ability for community members to edit it, and most importantly, there's no ability for anyone to vote on it. That's a significant problem when it comes to subject-matter content. It is antithetical to the entire purpose and mission of Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: @CodyGray solution would be to have a separate "site wiki" page (quite similar to 
 tag wiki, just meant for the whole site), not shove it inside the help center as SE is doing now.

Comment: Unnecessary, @Shadow. We already have Q&A, either self-answered or community wiki, that serve this purpose adequately using the existing model, and thus inheriting all of its advantages. There are also tag wikis, which trusted users already have permissions to edit, and others can suggest edits to.

Comment: Or put it in a meta post? [Similar idea](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) (awesome, BTW).

Comment: @CodyGray perhaps there is a post to decide what to write in there, so it has been voted and can be continually contributed by the community? I think there should be an official place to include help information about the subject too. There is a reason that this section can be edited after all.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I would say that I have checked at least 20 sites. Is the new title better?

Comment: @Mari-LouA I made your suggested title edit.

Comment: @SonictheWizardWerehog I can't believe it. IMO asking "why don't more site" is even more subjective than "what can be the reasons". I am about to change to "why shouldn't information about the site's subject be included in Help Page". What do you think?

Answer (score 3):

Simply put, if you had no idea about the topic if the site - you wouldn't need it.

Let's assume we had a SE site for that great academic field - underwater basket weaving. If you had no idea what underwater basket weaving was at all, you wouldn't need the site. If you had a basic idea of what it was - you would actually know what to ask questions about. It's a useful resource for sharing knowledge about underwater basket weaving, but it wouldn't be a place to find out *what* underwater basket weaving actually was.

In a sense - we expect people to have an interest and knowledge of a site they are involved in. We don't expect a new user to get the Q&A system (and certainly not the nuances) - and that's always been the point of the help center. We do have a little bit on what's on topic - since that's fuzzy, but a brief introduction to the topic of the site does not belong on the help center in my opinion.